# error: invalid type argument of 'unary *' (have 'int')|

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int _area(), _vol(), (*fnptr)();// declare the functions and the function pointer here

_area(a,b)
int a, b;
{
    return (a*b); //The return value of _area after parameters are passed to it
}
_vol(fnptr,c) //engaging the function pointer as a parameter
int c;
{
    fnptr = _area(); //initializing the function pointer to function _area
    int k = (*fnptr)(8,9); // error occurs here
    return (k*c);
}
```

Compiling produces an error ,

> :error: invalid type argument of 'unary *' (have 'int')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using function prototypes I believe the code should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int _area(int a, int b);

int _vol(int (*fnptr)(int, int), int);;// declare the functions and the function pointer here

int _area(int a, int b)
{
    return (a*b); //The return value of _area after parameters are passed to it
}

int _vol(int (*fnptr)(int, int),int c) //engaging the function pointer as a parameter
{
    fnptr = _area; //initializing the function pointer to function _area
    int k = fnptr(8,9); // error occurs here
    return (k*c);
}
```

Comment: would u mind explaining why are there types in the function pointer

Comment: The function pointer points to a function which returns an int and has two integer parameters. The function prototype requires the types of all parameters. The function pointer is a parameter to _vol function.

Answer (score 1):

```
**int k = (*fnptr)(8,9);** should be int **k = (*fnptr)(8,9);
```

Comment: sorry that was edited code as i tried to bold it then the asterisks were introduced

Comment: @user3106805 as a c programmer you should consider each and every character in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change `fnptr = _area()` to `fnprt = _area`. You want to point fnptr to the adress of _area function, not to call the function itself.

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  It looks like the poster does want to call the function.

Comment: it gives me a warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast when i do that plus the unary error is still there

Comment: The comment says in the code: "initializing the function pointer to function _area". That is why I made that assumption, why would you want to set the fnptr to the result of the _area function? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to call the function _area using the function pointer to perform operations on the parameters passed and the result used to compute the volume

Comment: So then my suggestion and assumption was correct. I would advise you to take a look on suspectus code example above and follow it.

Comment: To the person who gave me a minus please explain, I guess it was you Edward Thomson? Next time read the question and the answer a bit more carefully before any action please!